# Can the set of odd primes be finitely sieved by arbitrary congruences of primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This question arises from a previous one: [Can every infinite set be finitely sieved by arbitrary congruences of primes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610744/can-every-infinite-set-be-finitely-sieved-by-arbitrary-congruences-of-primes) which is solved and also contains the answer to two natural follow-up questions.

I have another non trivial follow-up question:

Denote with $\mathbb{P}$ the set of all prime numbers and let $I \subseteq \mathbb{P}$ a subset of the prime numbers.
Let $f : \mathbb{P} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(p) \in \{0,...,p-1\}$ for each $p \in \mathbb{P}$.
For each $p \in \mathbb{P}$ let $I_p = I \cap \{p + f(p), 2p  + f(p), 3p  + f(p), ...\} = \{q \in I : q \equiv f(p) \text{(mod }p\text{)}\}$.

The question is: is $I \cap \displaystyle \bigcap _{p \in \mathbb{P}} I_p^C$ necessarily a finite set for any choice of $f(p)$?

The question is essentially the same as the previous one, but instead of considering a generic $I \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ I want to focus to a more specific $I \subseteq \mathbb{P}$.

Note that the first value of the function (that is, $f(2)$) can be $0$ or $1$. If $f(2) = 1$ then $I_2 = \mathbb{P} - \{2\}$ and we are done. So we can assume $f(2) = 0$.

In the first comment received in the previous question there was the hypothesis that WLOG it was enough to consider $I = \mathbb{N}$, but I think that the received answers cannot be applied to this new case, so it is no immediate (at least for me) to find a counterexample.

I tried to do an experiment by considering $I = \mathbb{P} - \{2\}$ and defining $f(p) = 1$ for each $p \geq 3$. This way the sieved set will be something like $\{3, 5, 17, ... \}$ but I have no idea on how to dis/prove that this set is infinite.

EDIT: until $10000000 (10^7)$, the only primes that remains are $\{3, 5, 17, 257, 65537, ... \}$

This sequence sounds familiar... [Fermat primes](https://oeis.org/A019434). It is conjectured that this sequence is finite.

I will try with other choices of $f(p)$ and I will post here the results.

EDIT: I tried with $f(p) = p-1$. The sieved set (until $10^6$) in this case is $\{3, 7, 31, 127, 8191, 131071, 524287, ...\}$, see
[Mersenne primes](https://oeis.org/A000668)

EDIT: I tried with $f(p) = k$ where $p$ is the $k$-th odd prime $(f(3) = 1, f(5) = 2, ... )$ it seems that in this case each prime is filtered out, i.e. the final set is $= \emptyset$.

The same seems to happen with $f(p) = q$ where $q$ is the prime that preceed $p$ $(f(3) = 2, f(5) = 3, f(7) = 5, ...)$

Instead, with $f(p) = 2k$ (where $p$ is the $k$-th odd prime) then it seems that the sieved set is more *large*: there are $4328$ primes residual until the first $10^6$ naturals. The sequence starts with $$\{3, 7, 31, 37, 43, 61, 67, 73, 157, 211, 271, 277, 331, 367, ...\}$$ and it seems to be an unknown sequence in OEIS.

EDIT: I tried with $f(p) = n$ with $n$ constant. Results are this:

$f(p) = 2$ seems to lead to $\{3\}$ - the only prime in the form $1^n + 2$

$f(p) = 3$ (and $f(3) = 0$) seems to lead to primes in the form [$2^n + 3$](https://oeis.org/A057733)

$f(p) = 4$ (and $f(3) = 0$) seems to lead to primes in the form [$3^n + 4$](https://oeis.org/A102903)

$f(p) = 5$ (and $f(3) = 0, f(5) = 0$) seems to lead to primes such that [$p-5 \equiv 0\text{ (mod }\phi(p-5))$](https://oeis.org/A067557)

$f(p) = 6$ (and $f(3) = 0, f(5) = 0$) seems to lead to primes in the form [$5^n + 6$](https://oeis.org/A228029)

Don't really understand why 5 behaves differently. Don't know how to prove all of this empirical results, either.

Comment: Concerning the Fermat primes , there is an extremely good chance that there is none beyond $65537$. Of course we must sieve deeper and deeper to completely sieve out ever larger ranges , so I am not sure what you actually mean with sieving out an infinite set with finite many congruences. This is not possible in general.

Comment: The congruences are not finite, are infinite themselves. In other words, I want to sieve out an infinite set with infinite many congruences: for each prime $p$, I sieve out a certain set of primes that, mod $p$, are congruent with $f(p)$